# LibGdx изменение масштаба SpriteBatch

Tags: java, разработка-игр, libgdx

Пишу игру с огромным открытым миром, 1 метр = 1 единица измерения при рендере. После координат в несколько миллионов метров из-за неточности float типа, рендер начинает искажаться, но SpriteBatch принимает только float тип.

Вопрос: возможно ли сделать так чтобы все размеры

(включая `OrthographicCamera .viewportWidth` и `viewportHeight`)

можно было регулировать не вписывая везде такое `position.x*SCALE`?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то нужно делать так:

```
spriteBatch.getTransformMatrix().setToScaling(SCALE, SCALE, 1.0f);
```

вот только размеры спрайтов и текстур придется указывать тоже в метрах.